# Visualizing Schema using Workbase

Tags: vaticle-typedb

I am running Grakn Workbase on my Mac.

I created a schema and also accessed it using a console.

I try to visualize it using Grakn Workbase.

I open the application (version 1.2.7) and I click to select the keyspace.

I get the following message: "The transaction was refreshed, and as a result, the explanation of the currently displayed inferred nodes may be incomplete."

The logs says the following:

```
ERROR g.c.s.r.SessionService$TransactionListener - Runtime Exception in RPC TransactionListener: 
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT
    at grakn.core.server.rpc.ResponseBuilder.exception(ResponseBuilder.java:430)
    at grakn.core.server.rpc.SessionService$TransactionListener.handleRequest(SessionService.java:262)
    at grakn.core.server.rpc.SessionService$TransactionListener.lambda$onNext$1(SessionService.java:188)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please help. I do not know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workbase 1.2.7 isn't compatible with Grakn version 1.7.0 (there will be a new release soon). Please check if Workbase works if you use Grakn 1.6.2 instead!